# glob() can't find file names with multibyte characters on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, utf-8, filesystems, multibyte

I'm writing a file manager and need to scan directories and deal with renaming files that may have multibyte characters. I'm working on it locally on Windows/Apache PHP 5.3.8, with the following file names in a directory:

- filename.jpg
- имяфайла.jpg
- file件name.jpg
- פילענאַמע.jpg
- 文件名.jpg

Testing on a live UNIX server woked fine. Testing locally on Windows using `glob('./path/*')` returns only the first one, `filename.jpg`.

Using `scandir()`, the correct number of files is returned at least, but I get names like `?????????.jpg` (note: those are regular question marks, not the � character.

I'll end up needing to write a "search" feature to search recursively through the entire tree for filenames matching a pattern or with a certain file extension, and I assumed `glob()` would be the right tool for that, rather than scan *all* the files and do the pattern matching and array building in the application code. I'm open to alternate suggestions if need be.

Assuming this was a common problem, I immediately searched Google and Stack Overflow and found nothing even related. Is this a Windows issue? PHP shortcoming? What's the solution: is there anything I can do?

Addendum: Not sure how related this is, but `file_exists()` is also returning `FALSE` for these files, passing in the full absolute path (using Notepad++, the php file itself is UTF-8 encoding no BOM). I'm certain the path is correct, as neighboring files without multibyte characters return `TRUE`.

**EDIT**: `glob()` *can* find a file named `filename-äöü.jpg`. Previously in my `.htaccess` file, I had `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`, which I didn't consider before. `filename-äöü.jpg` was printing as `filename-���.jpg`. The only effect removing that htaccess line seemed to have was now that file name prints normally.

I've deleted the `.htaccess` file completely, and this is my actual test script in it's entirety (I changed a couple of file names from the original post):

```
print_r(scandir('./uploads/')); 
print_r(glob('./uploads/*'));
```

Output locally on Windows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => ??? ?????.jpg
    [3] => ???.jpg
    [4] => ?????????.jpg
    [5] => filename-äöü.jpg
    [6] => filename.jpg
    [7] => test?test.jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => ./uploads/filename-äöü.jpg
    [1] => ./uploads/filename.jpg
)
```

Output on remote UNIX server:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => filename-äöü.jpg
    [3] => filename.jpg
    [4] => test이test.jpg
    [5] => имя файла.jpg
    [6] => פילענאַמע.jpg
    [7] => 文件名.jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => ./uploads/filename-äöü.jpg
    [1] => ./uploads/filename.jpg
    [2] => ./uploads/test이test.jpg
    [3] => ./uploads/имя файла.jpg
    [4] => ./uploads/פילענאַמע.jpg
    [5] => ./uploads/文件名.jpg
)
```

Since this is a different server, regardless of platform - configuration could be different so I'm not sure what to think, and I can't fully pin it on Windows yet (could be my PHP installation, ini settings, or Apache config). Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing a `glob()` with a `*` mask? Re the `???????`, are you sure that isn't just a character set mismatch (between the file system's charset and your output charset)?

Comment: @Pekka: yes, added the pattern to the post, no flags.

Comment: Ugh, that's really surprising  behaviour. :( are you 100% sure only 1 element is returned? Did you do a `print_r()` on the raw `glob()` result? Remember, functions like `json_encode()` tend to silently drop stuff with invalid characters in them

Comment: Yes I did a `var_dump()` and there's only 1 item in the array. Straight raw PHP with no funny business. PHP 5.3.8 by the way.

Comment: Not being helpful here; it works in Linux. But when run via `wine php.exe` I only get two out of three multibyte filenames, with the UTF-8 bytes misdecoded as `��`. So I would bet on charset issues as well. But have you tried `GlobIterator` instead?

Comment: Selfishly adding `utf-8` tag so I'm sure to find this again in the future.

Comment: @mario: I'm trying `GlobIterator` but can't get it to run even with copy/paste examples from the manual. "Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'The parent constructor was not called: the object is in an invalid state" Thanks for the suggestion, I'll work on that.

Comment: Doesnt answer your question and im not sure if this will even solve this particular issue, but if youre open to using external libraries using the [Symfony Finder Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) would probably be a good fit for your end goal.

Comment: Check the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: @Jon: Thanks but I already have and there's nothing there. It's starting to become more apparent that this is an OS or configuration related problem that probably runs deeper than just `glob()`. Maybe someone using Windows and Apache can confirm these results?

Comment: `GlobIterator` does not behave differently either...

Comment: What a fascinating issue. Have you tried out `DirectoryIterator`? I'll set up a test case when I get home from work and give it a shot if you haven't.

Comment: @MetalFrog: I have not tried `DirectoryIterator`. Did you check out the article linked in the answer I just accepted?

Comment: +1 from me for the question I am looking since long time but not resolved yet for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the glob() function depends on how your copy of PHP was built and whether it was compiled with a unicode-aware WIN32 API (I don't believe the standard builid is.

Cf. http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/filesystem-encoding-and-php

Excerpt from comments on the article:

> **Philippe Verdy** 2010-09-26 8:53 am
>
> The output from your PHP installation on Windows is easy to explain :
>   you installed the wrong version of PHP, and used a version not
>   compiled to use the Unicode version of the Win32 API. For this reason,
>   the filesystem calls used by PHP will use the legacy "ANSI" API and so
>   the C/C++ libraries linked with this version of PHP will first try to
>   convert yout UTF-8-encoded PHP string into the local "ANSI" codepage
>   selected in the running environment (see the CHCP command before
>   starting PHP from a command line window)
>
> Your version of Windows is MOST PROBABLY NOT responsible of this weird
>   thing. Actually, this is YOUR version of PHP which is not compiled
>   correctly, and that uses the legacy ANSI version of the Win32 API (for
>   compatibility with the legacy 16-bit versions of Windows 95/98 whose
>   filesystem support in the kernel actually had no direct support for
>   Unicode, but used an internal conversion layer to convert Unicode to
>   the local ANSI codepage before using the actual ANSI version of the
>   API).
>
> Recompile PHP using the compiler option to use the UNICODE version of
>   the Win32 API (which should be the default today, and anyway always
>   the default for PHP installed on a server that will NEVER be Windows
>   95 or Windows 98...)
>
> Then Windows will be able to store UTF-16 encoded filenames (including
>   on FAT32 volumes, even if, on these volumes, it will also generate an
>   aliased short name in 8.3 format using the filesystem's default
>   codepage, something that can be avoided in NTFS volumes).
>
> All what you describe are problems of PHP (incorrect porting to
>   Windows, or incorrect system version identification at runtime) :
>   reread the README files coming with PHP sources explaining the
>   compilation flags. I really think that the makefile on Windows should
>   be able to configure and autodetect if it really needs to use ONLY the
>   ANSI version of the API. If you are compiling it for a server, make
>   sure that the Configure script will effectively detect the full
>   support of the UNICODE version of the Win32 aPI and will use it when
>   compiling PHP and when selecting the runtime libraries to link.
>
> I use PHP on Windows, correctly compiled, and I absolutely DON'T know
>   the problems you cite in your article.
>
> Let's forget now ***forever*** these non-UNICODE versions of the Win32
>   API (which are using inconsistantly the local ANSI codepage for the
>   Windows graphical UI, and the OEM codepage for the filesystem APIs,
>   the DOS/BIOS-compatible APIs, the Console APIs) : these non-Unicode
>   versions of the APIs are even MUCH slower and more costly than the
>   Unicode versions of the APIs, because they are actually translating
>   the codepage to Unicode before using the core Unicode APIs (the
>   situation on Windows NT-based kernels is exactly the reverse from the
>   situation on versions of Windows based on a virtual DOS extender, such
>   as Windows 95/98/ME).
>
> When you don't use the native version of the API, your API call will
>   pass through a thunking layer that will transcode the strings between
>   Unicode and one of the legacy ANSI or CHCP-selected OEM codepages, or
>   the OEM codepage hinted on the filesystem: this requires additional
>   temporary memory allocation within the non-native version of the Win32
>   API. This takes additional time to convert things before doing the
>   actual work by calling the native API.
>
> In summary: the PHP binary you install on Windows MUST be different
>   depending on if you compiled it for Windows 95/98/SE (or the old
>   Win16s emulation layer for Windows 3.x, which had a very mimimum
>   support of UTF-8, only to support the Unicode subsets of Unicode used
>   by the ANSI and OEM codapges selected when starting Windows from a DOS
>   extender) or if it was compiled for any other version of Windows based
>   on the NT kernel.
>
> The best proof that this is a problem of PHP and not Windows, is that
>   your weird results will NOT occur in other languages like C#,
>   Javascript, VB, Perl, Ruby... PHP has a very bad history in tracking
>   versions (and too many historical source code quirks and wrong
>   assumptions that should be disabled today, and an inconsistant library
>   that has inherited all those quirks initially made in old versions of
>   PHP for old versions of Windows that are even no longer officially
>   supported, by Microsoft or even by PHP itself !).
>
> In other words : RTM ! Or download and install a binary version of
>   PHP for Windows precompield with the correct settings : I really think
>   that PHP should distribute Windows binaries already compiled by
>   default for the Unicode version of the Win32 API, and using the
>   Unicode version of the C/C++ libraries : internally the PHP code will
>   convert its UTF-8 strings to UTF-16 before calling the Win32 API, and
>   back from UTF-16 to UTF-8 when retrieving Win32 results, instead of
>   converting PHP's internal UTF-8 strings back/to the local OEM codepage
>   (for the filesystem calls) or the local ANSI codepage (for all other
>   Win32 APIs, including the registry or process).

Comment: I'm giving this the checkmark for now, the project has gone to the backburner and I don't have time to recompile PHP and test this yet - but it sounds correct. I did read this article as it was linked in another comment here, but I did not read all the comments on it. I'm going to add some context to your post. The comment does mention: *"...use the UNICODE version of the Win32 API (which should be the default today)"* (in 2010)

Comment: So for anyone else reading this, I cannot confirm this. I've accepted the answer because I *believe* it may be true, although frankly I have no idea how my local PHP version was compiled. After several manual re-installs, I just use XAMPP now.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, Did you find out the solution to your question. If yes the please provide because handling Unicode really hurts lot :(

Comment: I am so sorry I lost the comments to the original article (from my blog), but this commentor was indeed extremely mistaken, and this was quickly confirmed by one of the core devs in that same thread.

Basically your only chance is to use COM or accept the fact that PHP on windows is not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set internal encoding inside in function (script).

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'C.UTF-8');
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer to the question. If you have tested this code with the provided sample filenames from the question, and you know it works, please include that information in the answer.

Comment: O.K.
I used this script in function, which builds folder based tree menu, find all sub-folders  and shows as tree menu,  Georgian, Japanese, Russian names.
It is too long and this page do not allow to write all function, but the part is like this:


<?php
function GetTreeMenu ($submenutree) {
 setlocale(LC_ALL,'C.UTF-8');
 $explodedpass=explode("/",$submenutree);//
 global $horizontalmenu;
}
?>

Answer (score -1):

PHP on windows does not use the Unicode API yet. So you have to use the runtime encoding (whatever it is) to be able to deal with non ascii charset.

Answer (score -1):

Starting with PHP 7.1 long and UTF-8 paths on Windows are supported directly in the core.

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question.

Comment: @miken32 yeah, thanks. Lesson learned already in another question. This issue is so many-faced, that it's probably impossible to chase it down to just one ticket. Quite a few tickets are there on  the stack overflow, but also on the PHP bug tracker and else where.

Comment: Btw, not sure why it needs to be a copypasted text from a moderator, anyway :)