# Save filename with unicode chars

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, windows-7

I have searched all over the Internet and SO, still no luck in the following:

I would like to know, how to properly save a file using `file_put_contents` when filename has some unicode characters. (Windows 7 as OS)

```
$string = "jérôme.jpg" ; //UTF-8 string
file_put_contents("images/" . $string, "stuff");
```

Resuts in a file:

```
jГ©rГґme.jpg
```

Tried all possible combinations of such functions as `iconv` and `mb_convert_encoding` with all possible encodings, converting source file into different encodings as well.
All proper headers are set, browser recognises `UTF-8` properly.

However, I can successfully copy-paste and create a file with such a name in explorer's GUI, but how to make it via PHP?

The last hardcore solution was to `urlencode` the string and save file.

Comment: Looks like you are passing UTF-8 where Windows expects input in a non-UTF-8 ANSI-codepage. Could also be that in your code you somewhere get UTF-8 but expect a single-byte encoding. How about Writing your proposed filename to a file and checking?

Comment: Well, I tried `iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $string);` which gives `jйrфme.jpg`, so what encoding Windows really expects?

Comment: Could you try running your program using the MS Tool [AppLocale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppLocale), setting the codepage to UTF-8?

Comment: I would like to avoid installing any additional stuff, since there should be some solution? Files are saved everywhere, unicode characters are widely used.

Comment: It looks like it's saving many of the characters as `cyrillic`; are you russian or something? either of these should work `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $string);`, `utf8_decode($string);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to iterate over non-English file names in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947941/how-to-iterate-over-non-english-file-names-in-php). I'm afraid it's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

*This might be late* but i just found a solution to close this hurting issue for me as well.
Forget about **iconv** and **multibyte** solutions; the problem [is on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659600/glob-cant-find-file-names-with-multibyte-characters-on-windows)! (in the link you'll find all it's beauty about this.)

After numerous attempts and ways to solve this, i met with [URLify](https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify) and decided that best way to cope with unicode-in-filenames is to *transliterate* them before writing to file.

Example of transliterating a filename before saving it:

```
$filename = "Αρχείο.php";   // greek name for 'file'
echo URLify::filter($filename,128,"",TRUE);
// output:   arxeio.php
```